# Combine multiple rows into one in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In sql server 2008, I have a table that has the columns [a],[b],[c],[sort] and it has 4 records:

```
1,      NULL,  NULL    0
NULL,   2,     NULL    1
NULL,   NULL,  3       2
10,     NULL,  NULL    3
```

I need to combine all the rows in a way that i get one row as a result, and for each column I get the first (ordered by sort column) non-null value. So my result should be:

```
1,      2,     3
```

Can anyone suggest how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Does your table actually only have such a small amount of rows? If so might as well just use a simple solution such as three `TOP` queries.

Comment: It will definitely have a small amount of records. Most likely less than 10. Can you show an example of what you mean by three TOP queries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way

```
SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 [a]
        FROM   @T
        WHERE  [a] IS NOT NULL
        ORDER  BY [sort]) AS [a],
       (SELECT TOP 1 [b]
        FROM   @T
        WHERE  [b] IS NOT NULL
        ORDER  BY [sort]) AS [b],
       (SELECT TOP 1 [c]
        FROM   @T
        WHERE  [c] IS NOT NULL
        ORDER  BY [sort]) AS [c]
```

Or another

```
;WITH R
     AS (SELECT [a],
                [b],
                [c],
                [sort]
         FROM   @T
         WHERE  [sort] = 0
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Isnull(R.[a], T.[a]),
                Isnull(R.[b], T.[b]),
                Isnull(R.[c], T.[c]),
                T.[sort]
         FROM   @T T
                JOIN R
                  ON T.sort = R.sort + 1
                     AND ( R.[a] IS NULL
                            OR R.[b] IS NULL
                            OR R.[c] IS NULL ))
SELECT TOP 1 [a],
             [b],
             [c]
FROM   R
ORDER  BY [sort] DESC
```

Comment: +1 - I started with three subqueries, but changed my mind, but your solution is more inline with what was asked.